# Can't Get my menu to open methods

Tags: java

I ideally want my program to open the method corresponding to the number.
I am doing this for school and do not understand why the code is not working as intended.

Any help would be appreciated and I hope this can be answered in a timely manner

```
import java.io.*;
public class Javavison {

static String name[]=new String[10000];
static int time[]=new int[10000];
static int day []=new int[10000];
static int positionCounter=0;

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    int menuChoice=1;
    System.out.println("Hello and Welcome to Javavision");
    while(menuChoice!=6){
        System.out.println("Enter Menu Choice");
        System.out.println("(1) Enter TV Shows/Add a TV Show");
        System.out.println("(2) Modify TV Show");
        System.out.println("(3) Delete TV Show");
        System.out.println("(4) Sort TV Shows");
        System.out.println("(5) Show all TV Shows");
        System.out.println("(6) Exit Program");

        BufferedReader in;
        in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try{
            menuChoice=in.read();
        }
        catch(IOException ie) {
             ie.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(menuChoice==1){
            addShow();
        }
        if(menuChoice==2){
            modShow();
        }
        if(menuChoice==3){
            deleteShow();
        }
        if(menuChoice==4){
            sortShow();
        }
        if(menuChoice==5){
            showShows();
        }
        if(menuChoice==6){
            break;
        }
    }
}

public static void addShow(){
    positionCounter++;
    BufferedReader in;
    in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter Name of Show");
    try{
        name[positionCounter]=in.readLine();
    }
    catch(IOException ie) {
     ie.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Enter Day of Show");
    try{
        day[positionCounter]=in.read();
    }
    catch(IOException ie) {
     ie.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Enter Time of Show(In military time, For example 2:30am=0230");
    try{
        time[positionCounter]=in.read();
    }
    catch(IOException ie) {
     ie.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void modShow() throws IOException{
    String name[]=new String[2];
    int forLoopCounter=0;
    BufferedReader in;
    in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter Name of Show that you would like to modify");
    try{
        name[1]=in.readLine();
    }
    catch(IOException ie) {
     ie.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(int a=1; a<=positionCounter;a++){
        forLoopCounter=a;
        if(name[1].compareTo(name[a]) ==0){
            a=positionCounter+2;
        }
    }
    if(forLoopCounter!=(positionCounter+1)){
        //allow user to modify information because name has been found
        System.out.println("Enter New Name: ");
        name[positionCounter] = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter New Time: ");
        time[positionCounter] = Integer.valueOf(in.readLine()).intValue();
        System.out.println("Enter New Day: ");
        day[positionCounter] = Integer.valueOf(in.readLine()).intValue();
    }
    else{
        //tell the user the name he entered is not in the data list
        System.out.println("Sorry The show you requested is not available");
    }
}

public static void deleteShow(){
    BufferedReader in;
    in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

}

public static void sortShow(){
    BufferedReader in;
    in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

}

public static void showShows(){
    BufferedReader in;
    in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
}
}
```

Comment: How is it not working as intended?

Comment: `the code is not working as intended` So what is intended?

Comment: I do not understand why some school still teaches their students to use BufferedReader to read input instead of using Scanner.

Comment: It just does another loop whenever i input a number I want it to go to the corresponding subroutine

Comment: You do realize that you are telling it to loop over and over again until the user inputs a "6", correct?

Comment: Am I how would i change this

Comment: Use a break statement in every if statement of your while loop in main. You said it loops over and over again, but which part loops over and over again?

Comment: Try out 11th dimension's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change BufferedReader to Scanner. Your BufferedReader is not reading in integers.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Javavison {

static String name[]=new String[10000];
static int time[]=new int[10000];
static int day []=new int[10000];
static int positionCounter=0;

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    int menuChoice=1;
    System.out.println("Hello and Welcome to Javavision");
    while(menuChoice!=6){
        System.out.println("Enter Menu Choice");
        System.out.println("(1) Enter TV Shows/Add a TV Show");
        System.out.println("(2) Modify TV Show");
        System.out.println("(3) Delete TV Show");
        System.out.println("(4) Sort TV Shows");
        System.out.println("(5) Show all TV Shows");
        System.out.println("(6) Exit Program");

        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        menuChoice=scn.nextInt();

        if(menuChoice==1){
            addShow();
        }
        else if(menuChoice==2){
            modShow();
        }
        else if(menuChoice==3){
            deleteShow();
        }
        else if(menuChoice==4){
            sortShow();
        }
        else if(menuChoice==5){
            showShows();
        }
        else if(menuChoice==6){
            break;
        }
    }
}

public static void addShow(){
    positionCounter++;
    BufferedReader in;
    in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter Name of Show");
    try{
        name[positionCounter]=in.readLine();
    }
    catch(IOException ie) {
     ie.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Enter Day of Show");
    try{
        day[positionCounter]=in.read();
    }
    catch(IOException ie) {
     ie.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Enter Time of Show(In military time, For example 2:30am=0230");
    try{
        time[positionCounter]=in.read();
    }
    catch(IOException ie) {
     ie.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void modShow() throws IOException{
    String name[]=new String[2];
    int forLoopCounter=0;
    BufferedReader in;
    in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter Name of Show that you would like to modify");
    try{
        name[1]=in.readLine();
    }
    catch(IOException ie) {
     ie.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(int a=1; a<=positionCounter;a++){
        forLoopCounter=a;
        if(name[1].compareTo(name[a]) ==0){
            a=positionCounter+2;
        }
    }
    if(forLoopCounter!=(positionCounter+1)){
        //allow user to modify information because name has been found
        System.out.println("Enter New Name: ");
        name[positionCounter] = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter New Time: ");
        time[positionCounter] = Integer.valueOf(in.readLine()).intValue();
        System.out.println("Enter New Day: ");
        day[positionCounter] = Integer.valueOf(in.readLine()).intValue();
    }
    else{
        //tell the user the name he entered is not in the data list
        System.out.println("Sorry The show you requested is not available");
    }
}

public static void deleteShow(){
    BufferedReader in;
    in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

}

public static void sortShow(){
    BufferedReader in;
    in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

}

public static void showShows(){
    BufferedReader in;
    in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have any quick recommendations?

Comment: @NickTitan So your actual problem is that you can't exit the loop?

Comment: I want to access the subroutines that the user requests?

Comment: @NickTitan I know what went wrong, but can you use Scanner instead of BufferedReader? I don't know why your school still use Java syllabus which is more than 10 years old.

Comment: How would I go about changing that?

Comment: @NickTitan I've been following Java syllabus from many institutes and universities. As far as I know, all of them had switched from using BufferedReader to Scanner. I think it's good if you learn it as well. After you replace all BufferedReader with Scanner, you can discard all the throw exception and try-catch block (which is not necessary in school level - until later topics) You were forced to use it just because of BufferedReader.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake was using in.read() to take a menuChoice.
InputStream.read() returns first byte of the input not the entire line, I have replaced the **in.read()** with **Integer.parseInt(in.readLine())**. Also I took the liberty to replace the ifs with the switch.

Now it's working

```
import java.io.*;

public class Javavison {

    static String name[] = new String[10000];
    static int time[] = new int[10000];
    static int day[] = new int[10000];
    static int positionCounter = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        int menuChoice = 1;
        System.out.println("Hello and Welcome to Javavision");
        while (menuChoice != 6) {
            System.out.println("Enter Menu Choice");
            System.out.println("(1) Enter TV Shows/Add a TV Show");
            System.out.println("(2) Modify TV Show");
            System.out.println("(3) Delete TV Show");
            System.out.println("(4) Sort TV Shows");
            System.out.println("(5) Show all TV Shows");
            System.out.println("(6) Exit Program");

            BufferedReader in;
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            try {
                menuChoice = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            } catch (IOException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }

            switch(menuChoice) {
                case 1:
                    addShow();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    modShow();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    deleteShow();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    sortShow();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    showShows();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    return;
            }

        }
    }

    public static void addShow() {
        positionCounter++;
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter Name of Show");
        try {
            name[positionCounter] = in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter Day of Show");
        try {
            day[positionCounter] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter Time of Show(In military time, For example 2:30am=0230");
        try {
            time[positionCounter] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void modShow() throws IOException {
        String name[] = new String[2];
        int forLoopCounter = 0;
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter Name of Show that you would like to modify");
        try {
            name[1] = in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int a = 1; a <= positionCounter; a++) {
            forLoopCounter = a;
            if (name[1].compareTo(name[a]) == 0) {
                a = positionCounter + 2;
            }
        }
        if (forLoopCounter != (positionCounter + 1)) {
            // allow user to modify information because name has been found
            System.out.println("Enter New Name: ");
            name[positionCounter] = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("Enter New Time: ");
            time[positionCounter] = Integer.valueOf(in.readLine()).intValue();
            System.out.println("Enter New Day: ");
            day[positionCounter] = Integer.valueOf(in.readLine()).intValue();
        } else {
            // tell the user the name he entered is not in the data list
            System.out.println("Sorry The show you requested is not available");
        }
    }

    public static void deleteShow() {
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    }

    public static void sortShow() {
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    }

    public static void showShows() {
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }
}
```